# Beginning electronics programming

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, raspberry-pi

I have substantial experience programming computers, but never programmed micro controllers or built digital equipment. The closest I ever came was controlling modems by reading & writing "registers" from interrupt handlers.

And now I'd like to build and program something physical, just as a hobby. I didn't decide on the scope of the project yet, but I'd like to be able to do more than LED flickering, maybe a toy car that would sense an object and change a direction, something like that, with both handling physical inputs and making mechanical motions.

So I'm looking for a starter kit that would be easy enough for a novice to begin and extendable enough to do more advanced things later. Googling things and asking around yielded Arduino, Raspberry Pi, Parallax, and Lego robotics kits. I'd like to get an advice which kits would be preferable for an experienced computer programmer but a complete novice in electronics to start with.

Also, I presume for most projects one would need a wide variety of electronic components beyond the micro controller and the board. I'd like a suggestions which kits would be best to start with.

One more thing: I'd prefer to connect components by plugging them into something like a breadboard rather than soldering, even for the completed project.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You are lucky. [The next iteration](https://www.edx.org/course/embedded-systems-shape-world-utaustinx-ut-6-03x) is starting soon.

Comment: We can't recommend a kit (assuming one exists) for an as yet unknown project. Also: is you experience in C/C++ (which are the dominant micro-controller languages), or some other language(s)?

Comment: Recommendation questions are off topic here. Even then, without a scope or idea of what you want to do, any of those is as good as the next. The RPi is a full blown Linux computer though, so you may be more comfortable with that

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen, I've programmed both C and C++ for living quite a lot. A little bin in x86 assembly as well.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: as for the project, something like a toy car that would follow the direction the voice is coming from but avoids obstructions would be perfect. Basically, handling audio and proximity inputs and controlling a couple of small motors.

Comment: Handling audio and in particular determining the direction of the audio is far from trivial. Try it first on a desktop system, PC or Pi. For a micro-controller, a line-follower or a right-hand-touches-the-wall maze walker is a more realistic project.

Comment: I wish you the best of luck in your future projects, but unfortunately requests for product recommendations are off-topic here. :-(

Comment: I had the same kind of background. I bought the official Arduino Start Kit that contains a book with some experiments. I am happy with that choice. In hindsight I notice that I could have bought all the components of the kit separately much cheaper though, but I still consider it a winner since it got me started with learning electronics. I am sure you will be inspired and project ideas will come to you spontaneously as you get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got several Arduinos, plus a couple of Raspberry Pi's.  I'm going to suggest the Arduino [Mega 2560](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006H0DWZW); it's got 256 KB Flash, which is plenty (way more than the Uno, which has only 32K), and 8 KB RAM, which is usually enough unless you are storing large arrays, and then you can get more RAM if you need to, like this 512 KB [expansion RAM board](http://hackaday.com/2011/09/05/upgrading-ram-in-an-arduino-mega/).

Get an authentic Arduino (like the one I linked to), some of the clones are iffy.

Both the Arduinos and Raspberry Pi's are expandable through "shields", which are stackable boards that contain various hardware goodies like motor controls, relays, wireless (Bluetooth, WiFi), and LCD screens.  You can also connect wireless breadboards using male to male jumpers (see picture below).  There are hundreds of shields.  Quite a bit more for the Arduino than the Pi.

The big difference between the two is ease of use.  With the Arduino, every  time you add some hardware there is usually a library download available that includes not only the driver code but also examples programs for checking out the board and showing off features.  I just got a 3.2" LCD plus touch panel running last night in less than 15 minutes.  The programming language is C++, so each peripheral will show up as a C++ class.  There is no OS, you are programming at the bare metal.

The Raspberry Pi on the other hand runs Linux and is more like programming a PC.  It of course has gobs of storage -- for example 1 GB of RAM with the [Raspberry Pi 2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-2-model-b/).  I just don't find it as accessible as the Arduinos.  I program my Raspberries in Python.

Both of these boards are small but still too big to fit inside a little toy car. However there are lots of projects for both the Arduinos and Pis for  controlling [robotic vehicles](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010XGLEKU).

[image]

You can see an Arduino (blue board with jumper wires sticking out of it) sitting on top.

Both Arduinos and Raspberry Pi's have their own forums here: [arduino.stackexchange.com](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) and [raspberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What is the authentic arduino for you, arduino.org or arduino.cc? You link goes to amazon.

Comment: @ott--  If you look under the product title "Arduino MEGA 2560 R3" on the Amazon link, it says "by Arduino".  So you are getting the same product as you would get from arduino.cc but a little cheaper ($37.77 vs $45.95).  Compare to [this one](http://www.amazon.com/SunFounder-ATmega2560-16AU-Board-compatible-Arduino/dp/B00D9NA4CY/ref=pd_cp_147_2?ie=UTF8&refRID=1K39TTQ8ADJS33WVN97W) which says "by Sunflower".  The clones are supposed to say "Arduino compatible". They are all legal as Arduino is open-hardware (it's not like you are buying a fake Rolex).  I just like supporting the Arduino project